# Trying to update a Facebook event using the Graph API (Facebook C# SDK)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to update the description of a Facebook event using the Facebook C# SDK. I have granted the following permission to my application:

'publish_stream,email,manage_pages,user_events,create_event,rsvp_event'

The event I am trying to update is one of my own events, so I believe I should be able to update it.

In the code below "9999" is the event id of the event I created, and the event I am trying to amend:

```
Authorizer authorizer = new Authorizer();
FacebookClient fbapp = new FacebookClient(authorizer.Session.AccessToken);
Console.Write(fbapp.Get("9999"));
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.description = "the new description";
fbapp.Post("9999", parameters);
```

The fbapp.Get works fine and returns the details of the event.

The problem is with the Post method, this returns `(OAuthException) (#200) Permissions error`

Any ideas as to where I am going wrong?

Comment: I have the exact same issue.
And yes I have requested the create_event permission and have verified in my app setting that my app now has the create_event permission.

I am trying to edit an event I just created today.  
I also get (OAuthException) (#200) Permissions error

Comment: I am still struggling to get this working. I have tried here, the Facebook Developers forum, and even directly asked a Facebook employee but no luck so far. I guess next step is to report this to Facebook as a possible bug.

Comment: A new version of Facebook SDK was released today at

Comment: I have not tried the new version yet, perhaps it will work...

Comment: Seems to be a Facebook bug, see this link for more detail:  http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=15590

Comment: This was also answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246178/facebook-update-event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is in fact a bug in the Facebook Graph API, see [here for the bug report](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=15590)

It appears to be the case that you can only use the Graph API to edit events created by your app, and not existing events created by users within Facebook.

Hopefully it will be fixed soon!

Comment: Just an FYI. The Facebook Bug has been closed with a "WONTFIX". An event created by the user can NOT be edited by your app.

Comment: your link is currently not working. Is this your source? http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/108521419302485?browse=search_5098507237d071328259370

Answer (score 0):

If you really have all permissions, I think you should include every mandatory field in the parameters (as I haven't done this, I can only guess!) and not only the field you wish to edit.

Hope this has helped you Andrew.

Comment: Hi Fabio - I tried this but it did not help, I still get the same error. Anyway, thanks for trying to help.

Comment: No problem, keep trying and them post a solution!